# POST and GET methods calling functions in the same file

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I've created an `insert.php` file where I have several insert functions. My forms are on different pages and some use `POST` and others use `GET` methods, but they all point to the `insert.php` file.

This was all coded in PHP5.2 and I didn't have much trouble specifying which insert function to execute based on which form is being submitted.  However, in my attempts to upgrade to procedural PHP7, I find that my submitted form doesn't necessarily point to the correct insert function in the `insert.php` file anymore.

Here is an example of how I am doing this:

**page1.php**

```
<form action='insert.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='form' value='data1'>
    ...
</form>
```

**insert.php**

```
if($_POST['form']=='data1') {
    //perform insert into db
}
```

I have different insert functions with different `$_POST['form']` variables.  Some of these functions are called from forms that use the `GET` method, so I have `if($_GET['form']=='data9') {...}.`

Questions:

1. Why are some of my forms not pointing to the correct insert function?
2. Is it better to put the `GET` and `POST` insert functions in different files, or is it okay to leave them in one file?
3. I'm thinking of possibly using the below code to solve question 2.

Any thoughts on this solution?

```
$form = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') ? $_GET['form'] : $_POST['form'];
```

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Comment: See above.  I fixed the formatting so you can now see the code.

Comment: So, i did this to solve/answer my second question, but first one still stands. if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
   $form = $_POST['form'];
} else {
   $form = $_GET['form'];
}

Comment: I usually write a seperate processing file for all my forms, unless they all do really similar actions.

Comment: Just use $_REQUEST['input']  Since $_REQUEST contains both $_GET and $_POST arrays there is no need to check both POST and GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:
$form = $_REQUEST['form'];

$_REQUEST will fetch both POST and GET request variables.

Hope this helps.